# Working with external developers on Azure project - how?

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure. I am getting myself confused very fast. My company has a project on Azure. We are looking to grant access to our external developers so they can log into our account and build a product for us ( setup a VM with mysql dbs and build an application ).

The only options I see are to invite users from another Active Directory or users who are in my own Active Directory?  Is there no option to simply create a sign in credential for a user with say " email at gmail dot com" ?

What am I missing? I have created a Resource group but still can't invite anyone of our external consultants in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can invite any user to manage your resources or your subscription.
There are 3 conditions for it:

- You have the right to add it to your Azure AD
- you are the owner of the subscription
- The 'Guest user' already has an Azure account or a Microsoft Account

Then you have to go to:

- Resources/Subscriptions
- Access Control
- Select a role (i.e. Contributor)
- Type in the Account/Email of your external team member
- check the checkbox and send the invitation

If you want to create generic users you can go straight forward to your AD and create a user i.e. developer1@contoso.onmicrosoft.com and add this user to the resource/subscription. Don't forget to take note of the credentials you created

Comment: What if the user doesn't have an Azure or Microsoft account? Just a gmail address?  Maybe, best i create a generic account for them ?

Comment: he then has the chance to create a microsoft account (https://signup.live.com >> Use your email address instead) with the gmail address and click on the invitation link afterwards

Answer (score 0):

So you would use Azure RBAC for that. Just click on the Resource Group > Access Control > Add.

[image]

You could also consult [this blogpost](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/07/30/good-practices-for-managing-windows-azure-subscriptions/) for best practises.

Comment: This assumes  "The 'Guest user' already has an Azure account or a Microsoft Account" ? I just tried it , didn't work ( my user doesn't have an Azure or Microsoft account )

Comment: mine neither, anyway, if that's the case, make them register, they are supposed to authorize in some way, how are they supposed to authorize without any kind of account?? I've just tested it and it just sends an email with invitation.

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with my setup then. Simply plugging in the email on that last step on the right in your screenshot fails. I go as far as that point.  I understand when they get the invite email they can sign up for a microsoft account or get authenticated. But why can't i send the email invite?

Comment: what does it say? can you provide a screenshot? i've just tested on a completely random email, it worked

Comment: You can't send the invite if you don't have administration rights in the active directory

Comment: I have admin rights - I own the account. It simply says " Failed to invite zzz@gmail dot com to xxx directory".  I just signed up for Azure yesterday - so on the free trial subscription. Does that matter?

Comment: You can own the account, the subscription and the company :) but if you are not an AD admin (not subscription/account admin) you won't be able to invite users to the active directory. Also check the permissions here https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UserManagementMenuBlade/UserSettings If you can't even see this page, then you are not an AD Admin

Comment: I can see the page you link to. So how do i go about setting myself up as an AD admin?

Comment: if you are not - yes

Comment: Not sure I understand your last comment. I can see the page . So does it mean I am an AD admin already? What next from there?

Comment: Can you set Yes to the values in the "External Users" section of the link I sent you and save?

Comment: navigate to your user and click > directory role, check if you are global administrator

Comment: yep - I am set as "global administrator"

Comment: at this point it looks like you need to contact support ;) can you try inviting someone with microsoft account?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need them to develop and access SQL or a web App, you can pass the publish profile and SQL connection string to them.
Also, you can setup continous integration for the web App or virtual machine and pass git or GitHub or whatever source control you are using and pass the URL for the project, then they will commit the source code and fire a new build